# Android - Getting the id of a ListView item [Special Case]

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursor

In my DB class have a method that returns a Cursor. the cursor will contain data from different tables:

```
public Cursor fetchFavTitles() {
    return myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT rowid as _id, title, fav FROM table1 " +
                                "WHERE fav = 1 UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT rowid as _id, title, fav FROM table2 WHERE fav = 1 UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT rowid as _id, title, fav FROM table3 WHERE fav = 1 UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT rowid as _id, title, fav FROM table4 WHERE fav = 1 UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT rowid as _id, title, fav FROM table5 WHERE fav = 1 UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT rowid as _id, title, fav FROM table6 WHERE fav = 1", null);

}
```

Then, I use a `SimpleCursorAdapter ca` to attach the `Cursor` to a `ListView lv` :

```
Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.fetchTitles(c);
String[] columns = {cursor.getColumnName(1)}; 
int[] columnsLayouts = {R.id.item_title};
ca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getBaseContext(), R.layout.items_layout, cursor,columns , columnsLayouts);
lv = getListView();
lv.setAdapter(ca);
```

Now, if I select any item in the ListView, I want to have a reference to that item id.
**I want the id to retrieve other information from the table the item belong to. And retrieve it in other activity MsgView**

I tried this:

- have a reference to the id passed when an item clicked
- pass that value with the intent, so that the other activity will retrieve the needed data using this passed value.

  ```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
          Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), MsgView.class);
              i.putExtra("id", (int) id); //
              startActivity(i);
      }
      });
  ```

However, this didn't work. It seems that the id I'm using is not the item's id !
Any solution or ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

Although it is not a professional solution, but it is the only one I have now. I added a new column in each table named: `tableNumber` so that each table will have a different number. Then, I can distinguish between items based on that number.

Thanks for your answers. and special thanks to @gopal

Comment: You can also specify the table by using a custom projection map, where some static value is aliased to an expected virtual column name, and each query in the `UNION` will specify its own value for the aliased column name;  something like: `"SELECT 'table1' AS type, rowid AS _id, title, fav FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT 'table2' AS type, rowid AS _id, title, fav FROM table2 ..."`. Then you can figure out which table the item came from by calling `String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));`

Answer (score 3):

In onItemClick method try this...

```
final SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
final Cursor cursor = simpleCursorAdapter .getCursor();

final int idColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID); //_id column of your table
final int rowId = cursor.getInt(idColIndex);
```

Used in one of my project here is [link](https://github.com/gopalB/FeedReader/blob/master/src/com/feedReader/FeedActivity.java) refer line number 41. Hope this help.

Edit:

***Solved***. See comments.

Comment: This will give me the `id` of the item that is selected, no clue to which table it belongs. I want to know `which table the item belong to` so I can retrieve it properly. Thanks @gopal

Comment: Ohkay gotcha, sorry for not understanding your problem correctly. Neway, I think it will be hard to find out which table id belong to because...when you are doing union all in the end you will get bunch of rows with title and fav as columns. I can see only one way for you to figure out which table it belongs when you have different values for each _id I mean some pattern. For ex table1 keys start with T1...table2 keys start with T2...and so on...some pattern to differentiate. Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

You want the position parameter not the id

See the documentation of onItemClick:

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

Since: API Level 1 Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.

Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

Parameters

> parent:   The AdapterView where the click happened.
>
> view:     The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)
>
> position:  The position of the view in the adapter.
>
> id:  The row id of the item that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static data member in your `MsgView` class that you use to store the id, or you can send a delayed message to the class, making sure that the activity gets loaded and started before the message arrives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [View.setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29) and [View.getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29) methods to store any data in your views. Sometimes I have exploited this to 'tag' a Intent object to each row in a ListView. Whenever I need to lookup data for a row i just get the Intent back with getTag()